# Visual Paradigm: Underline togetherness in class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

I have to create a class diagram with different design patterns inside. I would like to underline the togetherness of the classes belonging to the same design pattern.

What is the "official" or best way in UML to achieve this? I have to use Visual Paradigm and found a solution using packages.

[image]

But these packages seems to be very unhandy. I need something more freeform like. I think about just using different background colors for the different patterns.

Comment: I don't know VP but the above is ok. UML does not talk about coloring (basically only on p 17 of UML 2.5) - you are free to play Picasso at will ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The coloring of element is not the concern in UML as it won't affect the model structure and their relationships. Specifying different color is a good way for visualize categorize your elements in diagram level (same element on different diagram can have different presentation setting). If you want to categorize the elements in model level then you may consider to use stereotypes plus stereotype based presentations so that elements applying the stereotype can automatically inherit the presentation settings (see https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/stereotypeappearance.jsp)